# Henry's constant and solubility

Tags: solubility, solutions

According to Henry's law

> The solubility of gas in a liquid is directly
>   proportional to the partial pressure i.e S=Kp

My book says that higher the value of K at a given pressure lower is the solubility of the gas in the liquid. 
I don't understand how. I know I am overseeing something really simple over here as all the books that I have and online websites seem to conclude the same from the given equation. A little help maybe. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually solubility $x$ is given as a function of pressure $p$ and henry's constant $K_H$:
$$p=K_Hx$$

> My book says that higher the value of K at a given pressure lower is the solubility of the gas in the liquid. I don't understand how.

Since at a given pressure, $p$ is constant, if you increase $K_H$, logically solubility $x$ would decrease.

Comment: My book says that x is mole fraction! :(

Comment: @KaranSingh mole fraction can be treated as an indirect measure of solubility.

Comment: So would it be correct to say that mole fraction is directly proportional to solubility?

Comment: @KaranSingh approximately for dilute solutions.