# Confusion in solubility expressions in Henry's Law

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, solubility, solutions, ideal-gas

While reading about Henry's law and solubility I frequently come across two relations:

1. $C = k_{h}P$ (c = concentration of a dissolved gas)
2. $P = k_{h}x$ (x = solubility/mole_fraction)

What is the difference in these two expressions, do they seem to contradict each other? I am not able to decide whether a gas with higher $k_{h}$ would be more soluble or less soluble.
Please help me out with the same I am new to this topic

Comment: Please define all variables. Note that asterisk is not a proper multiplication sign and should never be used as such outside code listings. A meaningful title also wouldn't hurt.

Comment: kh in 1. is not the kh from the Henry law, but rather a solubility constant at given partial pressure. There should be used a different symbol for that. Note that the Henry constant uses the capital K.

Comment: @Poutnik google search of henry's law constant gives me that expression. Also I think I've read it elsewhere too. But as mentioned earlier I am not sure about this topic so it would be good if you could correct me wherever you think I am going wrong

Comment: It cannot be proportional to p ( in lower letter ) for the same molar fractions and at the same time reciprocal to p for the same concentrations. As  concentrations are not reciprocal to molar fractions. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry%27s_law for different used symbols.

Comment: @Poutnik Wikipedia mentions $H = \frac{x}{p}$ where x is the molar mixing ratio. I assume that they mean that x is the mole fraction. But isn't this formula different that what is used otherwise like in here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/29118/106010

Comment: @Poutnik Also incase that the symbols are different it would great if you could explain me the use case of both the expressions ? Like in what cases do we use expression 1 and in what expression 2.

Comment: There is more H constants there, with explicit superscript indexes, aside of K_H. The question is not, when to use which equation, but when to use which symbol and constant.

Comment: Okay I understand that's probably the reason for my confusion. But then in a nutshell if someone was to ask me the relation of solubility with henry's constant what would my answer be

Comment: Please see my answer. The notation used in your equations is obviously going to lead to a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sander (Ref. 1) has compiled a useful review of Henry's law constants in water that includes an introduction showing notation and conversions.

There are two types of Henry's law constants:

1. Solubility constants convert from pressure to concentration in solution (solubility):

$$c=Hp$$

2. Volatility constants convert from concentration in solution (solubility) to pressure:

$$p=Kc$$

Usually it is possible to determine which constant is reported by inspecting the units.

*References*

1. R. Sander. Compilation of Henry’s law constants (version 4.0) for water as solvent. *Atmos. Chem. Phys.*, **15**, 4399–4981, 2015.
   [www.atmos-chem-phys.net/15/4399/2015/doi:10.5194/acp-15-4399-2015](http://www.atmos-chem-phys.net/15/4399/2015/doi:10.5194/acp-15-4399-2015)